# Different VLans of seperate interfaces

Tags: routing, vlan, ethernet

**Background:** We're a very small company with a guest WLAN using captive portal authentification which by itself is working fine. Now we want to seperate the guests completly from our internal network ressources using vlans. In general this also works: The access points (TP-Link EAP110) add the vlan tag based on the SSID and the switch (D-Link DGS-1210) has an asymmetric vlan configured containing the AP ports and the external router allowing access to the internet while being on the guest wlan. The part where I am stuck is including the captive portal authentification since it is provided by one of the network ressources which we are trying to seperate from the guests.

**Issue:** So our server (running SLES11) has two ethernet interfaces, the first (`eth0`) being the only to be used up to now. My plan was to use the other one (`eth1`) for a second connection to the same switch but on a different vlan which is used by our guests, then utilize the firewall to only open port 80 on `eth1`.

I am unsure how to configure this setup. I looked up several vlan for linux ressources but these seem to always assume the machine is using only one connection. Currently, both `eth0` and `eth1` receive their ip-adresses from the DHCP to which I added a `vlan0` on the respective VID using `eth1` and the same ip as `eth1` (but static, at least for testing) but I can't get any response from the machine while being on the vlan (although I see packets with that VID arriving on that machine). It is responding fine on both ips from the main vlan. Also, I can't reach the outside world using `eth1` so my network configuration is wrong at some point:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:A6:BB:A4  
          inet addr:192.168.100.11  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17885592942 errors:0 dropped:80376 overruns:2811 frame:0
          TX packets:20780035729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21191101223489 (20209408.9 Mb)  TX bytes:24496578689971 (23361757.9 Mb)
          Memory:dfee0000-dff00000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:A6:BB:A5  
          inet addr:192.168.102.11  Bcast:192.168.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135707 errors:0 dropped:29 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:46277408 (44.1 Mb)  TX bytes:111178 (108.5 Kb)
          Memory:dfe60000-dfe80000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:445849353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:445849353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:307472500200 (293228.6 Mb)  TX bytes:307472500200 (293228.6 Mb)


# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.102.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

---

```
Machine1 (Main vlan) ping 192.168.100.11 - > success (ping arrives on eth0)
Machine1 (Main vlan) ping 192.168.102.11 - > success (ping arrives on eth0)
Machine2 (Guest vlan) ping 192.168.100.11 - > host not reachable
Machine2 (Guest vlan) ping 192.168.102.11 - > host not reachable
```

---

Screenshot of the Switch configuration:
[image]

- 35/36 are the APs
- 37 is eth0 of the server in question
- 45 is eth1 of the server in question
- 47 is the external router

Comment: did you set the PVID to 2 on port 47?

Comment: @JFL Changing the PVID of Port 45 does not change anything. Why changing it for 47 which is required in both vlans?

Comment: sorry misread, was for port 45. Port 45 should be untagged for vlan 2 and PVID set to 2. We should continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure VLAN on the linux server, but this is not needed.

The easiest way is to configure the switch so the port on which you connect eth1 is in access mode for the wanted VLAN.

Also VLAN 0 is a special VLAN, don't use it.

Note that you shouldn't have the same network (192.168.100.0/24) on 2 different interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: Removing the VLan on the server does not change anything, Independent on how the switch configures the port for eth1, it is never reached from within the vlan, vlan0 in that list is just the identifier, not the VID. I also tried it with different subnets (100/102) without any difference

Comment: @Bowdzone Make sure that the switch is configured so that the port for  eth0 is configured for one vlan and the port for eth1 is in a different vlan.  You do not need any vlan configuration on your server  - remove it.

Comment: @RonTrunk I removed the server-vlan configuration and the port on which eth1 is connected does not belong to the main vlan but only to the guest vlan, still eth0 and eth1 are reachable from the main vlan but not reachable from the guest vlan

Comment: @Bowdzone Can you post your switch config (edit your original question)?   I suspect you don't have that part right.

Comment: @RonTrunk posted

Comment: @bowdzone I see both interfaces are in the same subnet -- that's wrong.  eth1 should have an IP address in the guest subnet, not the main subnet

Comment: @RonTrunk You mean 192.168.100.11/192.168.100.68? As stated in my first comment I changed that to 192.168.100.11/192.168.102.11 without any difference

Comment: @Bowdzone sorry didn't see that.  Your switch is set right, so I suspect your server configuration.